# Same WP Query different results

Tags: wp-query, infinite-scroll

In a post list, I am currently reloading new posts with infinite scroll as soon as the visitor has reached the bottom area with the latest posts. In addition, the newly reached page is then appended as a url parameter page=X. If the visitor opens a post and goes back again, the url parameter should now be read out, depending on which page he has previously reached and accordingly all posts up to this page are displayed.
By default, 12 posts are displayed per page, if the visitor goes back with the parameter page = 2, 24 posts should be loaded. Wordpress recognizes the page parameter itself, but does not display all products up to this page, only the 12 products on this page. Accordingly, I would like to add a second query beforehand, which loads and displays the posts from the previous pages.

I noticed that although I duplicate the actual query and only adjust the posts_per_page and paged arguments, different results are returned. This happens even if I don't change anything in the query.

```
global $wp_query;
$custom_query_vars = $wp_query->query_vars;
$custom_query      = new WP_Query($custom_query_vars);

if ($custom_query->have_posts()) {
    while($custom_query->have_posts()) {
        $custom_query->the_post();
        echo get_the_id() . '<br />';
    }
}

echo '<br /><br />';

if (have_posts()) {
    while(have_posts()) {
        the_post();
        echo get_the_id() . '<br />';
    }
}
```

returns

```
84434
84904
85431
85927
86275
86779
87109
87411
87740
88153
88742
89269


84435
84905
85444
86004
86276
86780
87168
87486
87794
88238
88866
89273
```

Can someone tell me why the queries return different results? Thank you!